# Unable to specify `edition2021` in order to use unstable packages in Rust

Tags: rust, substrate, polkadot

I want to run an example via Cargo but I am facing an error:

```
error: failed to parse manifest at `/Users/aviralsrivastava/dev/subxt/Cargo.toml`
```

The full stacktrace is:

```
error: failed to parse manifest at `/Users/aviralsrivastava/dev/subxt/Cargo.toml`

Caused by:
  feature `edition2021` is required

  The package requires the Cargo feature called `edition2021`, but that feature is not stabilized in this version of Cargo (1.56.0-nightly (b51439fd8 2021-08-09)).
  Consider adding `cargo-features = ["edition2021"]` to the top of Cargo.toml (above the [package] table) to tell Cargo you are opting in to use this unstable feature.
  See https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/cargo/reference/unstable.html#edition-2021 for more information about the status of this feature.
```

Based on the suggestion, I go ahead and modify the Cargo.toml:

```
  Consider adding `cargo-features = ["edition2021"]` to the top of Cargo.toml (above the [package] table) to tell Cargo you are opting in to use this unstable feature.
diff --git a/Cargo.toml b/Cargo.toml
index 26a02c7..186d09b 100644
--- a/Cargo.toml
+++ b/Cargo.toml
@@ -1,6 +1,6 @@
 [workspace]
 members = [".", "cli", "codegen", "macro"]
-
+cargo-features = ["edition2021"]
 [package]
 name = "subxt"
 version = "0.15.0"
(END)
```

I still face the same error as if nothing was changed in the toml file.

How do I resolve the above error in order to use unstable packages?

Comment: What about downgrade your toolchain?

Comment: What does that mean? Sorry I am new here.

Do you mean subxt downgrading or substrate node?

Comment: Your rust version.

Comment: How do I do that? `rustup default <version_number>` ? Which version should I move to?

Thanks

Comment: Try nightly-2021-04-22.

Comment: It did not work out. Same error.https://pastebin.com/rtxZdtLi

Comment: Then what about `rustup default nightly && rustup update`
I clone the subxt repo, which works fine for me.

Comment: That worked. Thanks! Mind answering this?

Comment: @AviralSrivastava Can you please support the Substrate StackExchange proposal: https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/126136

Comment: Haha @ShawnTabrizi sir, I already did. Couple of days ago when I saw the word in Discord. Gonna circulate it among my circle too.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Update the Rust to satisfy the new edition 2021.

`rustup default nightly && rustup update`

Thanks to @ken.
Yes, you can use the `stable` channel too!

*But I love `nightly` personally.*

Comment: I ran into this issue this morning using my Intel Mac and just ran `rustup update` on the stable branch and that was enough ... had been using 2021 edition without issue on my M1 Mac all weekend without issue but maybe it was running the updated version. Anyway, 2021 is a stable release now.

Answer (score 18):

Edition 2021 is now part of the [stable channel](https://forge.rust-lang.org/index.html#current-release-versions).

As what happened to me, you probably just need to update your stable version by running `rustup update stable`.

That should fix the issue, and not require you to switch over to the nightly channel.

Comment: this should be the top answer now!

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 -sSf https://sh.rustup.rs | sh -s -- -y
source $HOME/.cargo/env && rustup default nightly && rustup update
```

Comment: This worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Seen this error twice when working with Solana. You can get this error if Solana is not up to date. Update it with `sh -c "$(curl -sSfL https://release.solana.com/v1.10.26/install)"`

Or preferably find the latest version and instructions here
https://docs.solana.com/cli/install-solana-cli-tools

Answer (score 0):

Some machines (including those with M1 chips) may be unable to build