# rust unable to run edition2021

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I'm trying to run a project in rust. I keep running into this edition 2021 error:

```
% rustc --version
rustc 1.60.0-nightly (a7e2e3396 2022-01-08)
```

I ran all this:

```
If you are trying to migrate from the previous edition (2018), the
process requires following these steps:

1. Start with edition = "2018" in Cargo.toml
2. Run cargo fix --edition
3. Modify Cargo.toml to set edition = "2021"
4. Run cargo build or cargo test to verify the fixes worked
```

I keep getting this error:

```
Failed to obtain package metadata: Error during execution of cargo metadata: error: failed to parse manifest at /workdir/program/Cargo.toml

Caused by:
  the cargo feature edition2021 requires a nightly version of Cargo, but this is the stable channel
```

I'm at a total loss here. I've found a lot of conflicting information. I've changed directories, found answers on SO like this: [Unable to specify `edition2021` in order to use unstable packages in Rust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69848319/unable-to-specify-edition2021-in-order-to-use-unstable-packages-in-rust)

I'm at a total loss here. What is the step I'm missing here? I'm on MacOS Big Sur.

Comment: It looks like you're running a stable Cargo but nightly rustc. What is the result when you type `cargo --version`?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman cargo 1.60.0-nightly (358e79fe5 2022-01-04)

Comment: did you solve this?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that, for your specific package, cargo (rustc) stable is used because of "...but this is the stable channel". Maybe a different compiler channel is defined for your package via rustup. Then this specific channel is always used, regardless of the global default. If you are *inside* the package, you can use `rustup show` to display the active toolchain. Maybe it says that stable is used for that package. Then consider removing this override with `rustup override unset` and try running it again.

EDIT: Because edition 2021 is stable for a while, you might consider updating rustc and cargo with `rustup update`, and then your project should be able to run with the stable compiler if you do not use any other nightly features.

Answer (score 1):

Do **not** use `cargo-features = ["edition2021"]` setting. It's obsolete and must not be used any more. Completely remove it from all `Cargo.toml` files. The instruction to add this was printed by an outdated, unsupported, experimental compiler version that you're not supposed to be using any more.

You don't need to use a nightly version for the 2021 edition any more. It's been stable and widely usable since December 2021. You just need to update your Rust to a stable version 1.56 or later.

If you happen to be using an outdated Rust package from a slow-moving Linux distribution, uninstall it, and install Rust via https://rustup.rs instead.

Comment: Can you please cite a reference for "obsolete and must be used anymore"? I'm not doubting what you're saying here, it would just be helpful for a Rust beginner (me) to see the context. I thought backward-compatibility was one of Rust's selling points, and this is not making that case very well.

Comment: `cargo-features =` exists only for opting in to unfinished, experimental, unstable "nightly" features. Once something is released for real, it's not a "nightly" feature any more, and nightly-opt-in for it stops working.