# cargo version 2021 required on Solana anchor build

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, solana

I am trying to run anchor build and am receiving the following response:

```
BPF SDK: /root/.local/share/solana/install/releases/1.8.0/solana-release/bin/sdk/bpf
Running: rustup toolchain list -v
Running: cargo +bpf build --target bpfel-unknown-unknown --release
error: failed to download `solana-frozen-abi v1.9.4`

Caused by:
  unable to get packages from source

Caused by:
  failed to parse manifest at `/root/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/solana-frozen-abi-1.9.4/Cargo.toml`

Caused by:
  feature `edition2021` is required

  consider adding `cargo-features = ["edition2021"]` to the manifest
```

PS: I have already tried suggestions at: [Unable to specify `edition2021` in order to use unstable packages in Rust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69848319/unable-to-specify-edition2021-in-order-to-use-unstable-packages-in-rust)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like your solana install is quite out of date. I would install either `1.8.11` or just run `solana-install update`

Comment: Thanks @[Jacob Creech](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17245830/jacob-creech). It worked. Was stuck in this for an hour!

Answer (score 0):

At times, also consider downloading to like in my case I had to change from 2021 in my `Cargo.toml` file to 2018 and this has worked